# How to create an RDD from a Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

my question is very simple.
I want to convert the line below to an RDD.

```
Row("val1","val2")
```

Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: Do you need the output to be RDD[Row] or RDD[String]?

Comment: To you want each element in the row to be a record in the RDD, or do you want an RDD[Row] that just contains the single row object?

Comment: I would like one line with two column, wich would be an Rdd of Row

Comment: `sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("val1","val2")))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val abc = Row("val1","val2")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(abc))
val rowRdd = rdd.map(row => Row(row.toSeq)) 
rowRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sc.parallelize(List(Row("val1","val2")))
```

is fine

Comment: You need to add some explanation to your solution, what's `sc`, what's `parallelize`?

Comment: sc is the SparkContext